# Infer/type hint superclass __init__ args in child?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to see whether it is possible to solve the following problem

Suppose I have to classes:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, param: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        ...

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        ...
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

When using pyright, I don't get any (type) checking on arguments to class A since the B's **kwargs just take all arguments.
Is it possible to type hint class B to mimic A._*init*_'s signature?

In older posts the main solution seems to be to just redefine `param`, however in my case A's signature might change over time and I would prefer it if I didn't have to touch B in those cases.

I was hoping this was maybe achievable with the "somewhat recent" additions of `TypeVar` and `ParamSpec`. I went down a rabbit hole where I would have class `B` have a more generic signature:

```py
P = ParamSpec('P')
T = TypeVar('T')

class B(Generic[P, T]):
    def __init__(self, cls: Type[T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
        ...
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

But in this case `B` obviously wouldn't inherit from my generic `T` and I'm not even sure whether that's possible or would even solve my problem so I stopped pursuing that road

Comment: you might be able to use a `TypedDict`, but what's wrong with just typing out the keyword args explicitly? I reckon that's better than bending over backwards to avoid typing some parameters twice. If you have lots of parameters, your real problem might be too many parameters

Comment: The problem is that I am extending a class from a third party library, so I don't really have control over the number of arguments, and if I understand it correctly if I used a TypedDict I would need to maintain the keys and types myself

Comment: @Travior then there's not much you can do unfortunately

Comment: Alright, almost figured as much. Should I just leave this question open in case such a thing becomes possible later or is it better to delete this as it isn't possible?

Comment: It's hard to say more without knowing more, but even if you subclass `A` (rather than e.g. wrap it), you still have flexibility in the signature of `__init__`

Comment: What do you want to override the `__init__` method for? Do you merely want to run some code prior to the initialization or are you extending the `__init__` signature with some extra parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you merely want to run some custom logic in the child class' `__init__`, a decorator approach will preserve the signature without the need to explicitly repeat it.

```py
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, Protocol, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
SelfT = TypeVar("SelfT", contravariant=True)


class Init(Protocol[SelfT, P]):
    def __call__(__self, self: SelfT, *args: P.args, **kwds: P.kwargs) -> None:
        ...


def overinit(init: Callable[Concatenate[SelfT, P], None]) -> Init[SelfT, P]:
    def __init__(self: SelfT, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
# put your code here
        init(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return __init__


class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: str, c: float) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


class Child(Parent):
    __init__ = overinit(Parent.__init__)


Child(1, "123", 123)
```

Comment: This works quite nicely in my use case. Thank you very much